# Menu Principal do PyCharm sumiu

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

estou começando os estudos em Python e depois de ficar explorando o PyCharm, acabei tirando o menu principal dele e não sei como fazer para voltar kkk
Alguém poderia me dar uma ajudinha, por favor?

[image: print de como ficou a parte superior]

Observações:
-Versão do Ubuntu:20.04.4 LTS
-Vesão do PyCharm: 2021.3.3 (Professional Edition)

Obrigada desde já!

EDIT:
Em anexo a foto do MainMenu em ON e mesmo assim sem aparecer :(
[image: imagem do main menu com ON]

Answer (score -1):

Olá, tudo bem?
Bom tente usar estes comandos:

Control + shift + all > clique na barrinha all > digite "main menu" > vai aparecer uma barra escrita "View Appearance: Main menu" ai vai ta OFF, você clica nela para ativar (ON)!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Descobri que além de estar dando esse problema com o PyCharm, também está com meu Intellij. Verifiquei aqui e nos dois a opção está como ON e mesmo assim não aparece :( . Coloquei na pergunta com edit...